# How to handle many to many relationships in mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, many-to-many

What is the best way to structure many-to-many models in a mongoose schema?

I have two models that have a many-to-many relationship with eachother. Users can belong to many organistaions and Organisations can have many users.

Options:

1. Define the relationship in **each** model by referencing the other model
2. Define the relationship in **one** model by referencing the other model

Option 1

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  organiations: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Organiation" }, // references organisation
})

mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)

const OrganiationSchema = new Schema({
  users: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }, // references users
})

mongoose.model("Organiation", OrganiationSchema)
```

This seems like a good idea at first and it means I can query the Organisation model to get all users and I can also query the user model to get all relative organisations.

The only problem with this is I have to maintain 2 sources of truth. If I create a organisation, I must update the user witht the orgs it belongs to and I must update the organisation with the users it has.

This leads me to option 2 which is to have one source of truth by only defining the relationship in one model.

option 2:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  organiations: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Organiation" }, // references organistion
})

mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)

const OrganiationSchema = new Schema({}) // no referencces

mongoose.model("Organiation", OrganiationSchema)
```

This means when I create a new organisation I only need to update user with the organisations they belong to. There is no risk of the 2 sources getting out of sync. However, it does mean when it comes to querying data, it makes it more tricky. If I want to get all users that belong to an organisation, I have to query the user document. This would mean my organisation controller has to then be aware of both user and organisation models and as I start adding more relationships and models, I get tight coupling between all of these modules which I want to avoid.

How would you recommend handling many-to-many relationship in a mongoose schema?

Comment: You are right about the options, don't forget option  1 has the potential issue of a large organization having many users in its user list. The choice between the two strategies is yours to make.

Comment: You're right that large organisations could have many users. But this can be an issue for option 2 as well. If I am trying to find all users which have organisation._id in their organisations array, then it's not very elegent. Not sure how mongoose handles this but could be a potential performance issue.

Comment: If you really care about performance you need to prioritize the requirements (query time/storage space/query flexibility) and tune your schema to these requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're alluding to when you mentinoed organizations having mahy users then. How does that only affect option 1 and not option 2?

Comment: If you have one organization with 10000 users, each of the users has a single org in the organizations array but the org has 10000 users in its users array. It's less likely that a user will belong to 10000 organizations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed solution to this.

If the organization can have orders of magnitudes more users than users can have organizations, option 2 might be a better solution.

Performance wise, populating the referenced data would be about the same as long as the referenced ids are indexed.

Having said that you might still go for option 1, even if you organization collection has the potential to have "huge" arrays. Especially if you want to make simple computation such as number of organizations users or use the "organiztion's current userIds to some other collection". In this case option 1 would be way better.

But if you opt of option 1 and if your array has the potential to become very large, consider bucket design pattern. Basically you limit the max length of your nested array. If the array reaches its max length, you make another document that holds newly added ids(or nested documents). Think of it as pagination.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to try avoid large arrays of data. I didn't consider a bucket design pattern. You mean similar to how mysql handles many-to-many relationships with a mapping table of sorts which has the key / ID for each item? In mongo's case, create a new document which references user._id and organisation._id?

Comment: yeap but a lot better that sql way. instead of referencing single set of user._id and organisation._id, you store array of user._id with a single organization._id. Basically in most cases you wont event need to extend your original orgainization document. But if for some reason the number of users in organization grows too large(ex 100,000) then you can make a refering document that can store another 100,000 users in a single extended document

Comment: have a look at this link: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one source of truth as you mentioned in solution 2, but for querying you can use virtual populate for the other side:

```
// add the following to your Organization model
OrganiationSchema.virtual("users", {
  ref: "User",
  foreignField: "organiations",
  localField: "_id",
});
```

Then you can populate `users` in your query:

```
Organiation.findById(id).populate("users").exec();
```